# To Prove that $(X,d)$ is not separable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be the set of sequences in $[-1,1]$. Define $d$ on $X\times X$ to be $d(a,b) := \sup\{|a_n -b_n| :n \in \mathbb N\}$. Then $d$ is a metric on $X$; and show that $(X,d)$ is not separable.

I am able to prove that $d$ is a metric. 
And for proving this to be not separable.... I want to bring a contradiction by assuming that it is separable. And to prove that a metric space is separable we have to show that it has a countable dense sets. Thus we have to show that $(X,d)$ has uncountable dense sets....but I am not able to do the proof!! Please HELP.

I found the problem in one exercise of Searcoid's Book on Metric Spaces.

Thank You!!

Comment: Be careful with the last comment you made - you don't need to show that there are uncountable dense sets, as a separable space can have uncountable dense sets, for example the irrationals form an uncountable dense set in $\mathbb R$. Maybe what you meant to say say was all dense sets are uncountable.

Comment: so if i want to prove it by contradiction then what will it have to assume?? @Dom

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose $S \subset X$ is countable.  Then, we can enumerate it, say as $\{x_n^{(k)}\}$.  What can we say about the sequence $\{y_n\} = \{x^{(n)}_n \pm 1\}$ (where the $\pm$ is chosen independently for each $n$ so that $y_n \in [-1,1]$)?